# How do you obtain manure in Farming Simulator 20 (Nintendo)?

Tags: farming-simulator-20

Nintendo Switch here (Farming Simulator 20). I am brand new to the entire FS series and just purchased a manure spreader so that I can fertilize my fields to improve crop yield.

I am really struggling to find *where* and *how* I fill my spreader with manure! So I ask: **where (*specifically*, on the map!) do I get manure from, and how do I fill the spreader with it?**

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a PC version of Farming Simulator 20.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the edit @Wrigglenite (+1) -- there _is_ an FS20 for [mobile](https://www.farming-simulator.com/about.php?lang=en&country=us&platform=mobile) so I made a quick edit to reflect I'm talking about the Switch version and not the mobile version.

Comment: Is the game any different on mobile?

Comment: That is what I've gathered from talking to other long-time players, but I don't have the mobile version so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after experimenting **a lot** here is what I have found:

1. Manure can only be obtained if you have your own cows or horses (which I currently do not). If you have cows or horses, their manure will appear in the respective silage bins at the farm/cow pasture
2. If you don't have animals yet, you can use liquid or solid fertilizer instead
3. For liquid fertilizer, buy a sprayer and hook it up to a tractor. Drag the sprayer over to the liquid fertilizer tank at the farm/cow pasture and it will fill up automatically. Use the symbols on the ground to know which tank hold liquid fertilizer; you can find these symbols in the help docs.
4. For solid fertilizer, buy a fertilizer implement and hook it up to your tractor. Do the same as above but with the solid fertilizer tank.
5. Certain seeders allow you to plant and fertilize at the same time. Read their information in the equipment to know which ones can do this. Totally worth the investment and huge time saver. Fill them up with seed at the seed silo and then fill them up with fertilizer at the desired tank.